# Pushing to git repository cloned from KIE Workbench repository

Tags: git, drools, drools-guvnor, kie, kie-wb

I use KIE Workbench (6.1.0.Beta3) to edit my rules. Since there are some features not being supported by the Workbench yet (e.g. moving rules to other packages), I would like to do this stuff outside of KIE-WB.

For that, I cloned my repository with

```
git clone git://localhost:9418/my-kie-repository
```

which works fine. I edit some files, commit them locally and try a `git push` afterwards. But I get the error

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

Since I am almost certain it is the first issue, something about credentials, I added to the `.git/config` file the lines

```
[credential "git://localhost:9418"]
    username = admin
    password = admin
```

Still, I get the previously mentioned error. And yes, the KIE Workbench is still running, I can also fetch/pull from there without problems.

Is there any way how to push back to that KIE Workbench repository? According to [this message](http://drools.46999.n3.nabble.com/How-to-push-changes-to-cloned-repo-on-Kie-Workbench-tp4027264p4027266.html), one "might need to reconfigure origin", but I am unsure about how to change it.

Anyone an idea how to set this up correctly?

Comment: Git protocol provides no authentication and is read-only. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: Thank you, @kaman, but how am I supposed to push then to that repository? I cannot clone with ssh (my admin-login credentials don't work), hence I can't push there. What are the correct credentials for pushing to that KIE Workbench repository?

Answer (score 2):

With **Kie 6.5** I had a similar problem, couldn't push to kie-wb's git repository.

Following is how I found a way to push.

First clone your wb repo with the **ssh** protocol rather than **git**.

```
git clone ssh://kuser@localhost:8001/repository
```

**kuser**: your wb user

**repository**: your wb repo name

P.S. I did that with eclipse and needed to tell it the pwd too.

When you try to interact with the repo you've just cloned, you'd get an authorization error.

```
$ git pull                                                                                         
Unable to negotiate with 127.0.0.1 port 8001: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-dss
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                      

Please make sure you have the correct access rights                                                
and the repository exists.
```

Looks like **Kie-wb 6.5** 's **git**'s ssh server relies on dsa (dss) authentication.

So you might need to tell your git client to talk wb's git's ssh server language (auth algorithm):

```
$ git config core.sshCommand "ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss"
```

After that if you try again to pull you'll get prompted for your wb user pwd, type it and you're ok:

```
$ git pull
Password authentication
Password:
Already up-to-date.
```

With eclipse git client you can save your credentials and won't have to write it every time.

It's even better to setup a dsa key and authenticate that way but unfortunately I didn't succeed to make it work till now although I could add my dsa key to the ssh server.

Answer (score 1):

I find the ssh protocol request can deal with the request;

```
 $ git clone ssh://adminsf1@10.101.81.72:8001/uf-playground
cloning 'uf-playground'...
Authenticated with partial success.
Password authentication
Password: 
remote: Counting objects: 967, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (967/967)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (459/459)
remote: Total 967 (delta 385), reused 967 (delta 385)
receiveing objects: 100% (967/967), 154.58 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
dela with delta : 100% (385/385), done.
complete。

$ echo "heello" >> hello2
$ git add hello2 
$ git commit -i -m "add hello2 now" hello2 
[master a78762f] add hello2 now
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 hello2
$ git push
Authenticated with partial success.
Password authentication
Password: 
Counting objects: 5, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 271 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1)
remote: Updating references: 100% (1/1)
To ssh://adminsf1@10.101.81.72:8001/uf-playground
   273c880..a78762f  master -> master
```

take attention about the user: adminsf1

this user is add by add_user.sh of jboss/bin

Some tips:
1. there is no generating ssh-key and stroing to Guvnor .security directory work :<,
i donnot understand what the function of the .security directory form the "org.uberfire.nio.git.ssh.cert.dir: Location of the directory  .security where local
certtificates will be stored. Default: working directory"

there are no more information exclude one file named hostkey.ser after add users :<

1. i fail with using git protocol to push code to guvnor git server as well,
   however i can clone from git

this is what i do not understand ye

good luck

Comment: Thank you, but which roles did you give for the user adminsf1? I tried to use my regular KIE WB user now, but authentication fails although the credentials are correct. Which OS do you use to run KIE WB? We have a windows system, may that be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

@gammachen's ssh example should work for you. I am running kie-wb on tomcat 7.

I have the following user:

```
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-gui,admin"/>
```

You can then do something like:

```
git clone ssh://tomcat@localhost:8001/uf-playgroundere
```

In my case password will be `tomcat`.

My .git/config looks like:

```
]$ cat uf-playground/.git/config 
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://tomcat@localhost:8001/uf-playground
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open new folder on your desktop
2. Enter and open git bash here
3. Call commands like

   ```
   git init
   git config core.sshCommand "ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss"
   git pull ssh://admin@0.0.0.0:8001/uf-playground
   ```

   Enter admin user password (default: admin)

Comment: That is basically what @gammachen answered three years ago, using SSH instead of the git protocol. But I don't work on that tech any longer, so I can't check that, sorry ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by adding the following to the config file under .ssh

Host localhost
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-dss