# How do I sync my Drools workbench with git repository

Tags: git, synchronization, drools

I have a need to sync my Drools workbench with Git repository. Are there any steps to do it. The Drools workbench is running on a linux machine.

I'm running 3 shell scripts written by someone else but

spawn git clone ssh://username@localhost:8001/MySpace/reponame is not executing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a bit more than "not executing" to debug this.

Try at least a `ssh -Tv username@localhost:8001` to check if SSH is working.

Consider also using a simple local path if you are cloning a repository which is already on your `localhost` (local machine):

```
git clone /MySpace/reponame
```

If you are using a Docker image, see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/g/drools-setup/c/Fyjejhiz3gM)

> it's not related to the docker container itself, it just should do the "bridge" between container and hosts ports.

If not, check if, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42143385/6309), you need a:

```
git config core.sshCommand "ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I tried sh -Tv username@localhost:8001 and got
ssh: Could not resolve hostname localhost:8001: Name or service not known

Comment: @Abhijit That would explain why the `git clone ssh://username@localhost:8001/...` is not running. Do you have any documentation on Drools workbench which would explain the prerequisites? Like "ssh daemon" should be running?